# Scopes reboot non stop, language of the system is changed, computer can't open the peripheral

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, mtp, scopes

I got a problem with my ubuntu touch phone (aquaris E4.5). 
Today  there was an update, I thought it was the OTA-4 but checking the parameters it was display ubuntu 14.10 (r22). 
Everything worked fine but some minutes ago I plugged my phone into my computer (that run arch linux btw), and it said :

> Impossible d'ouvrir le périphérique MTP « [usb:010,002] »

the translation would be :

> Impossible to open the MTP peripheral « [usb:010,002] »

Of course it used to work fine, and I could transfer my photos, music, videos from my phone to the computer, and vice versa. 
I change the USB port, it didn't worked. I changed the usb cable, still didn't worked.
And here comes this bugs of my phone : 
My phone is no longer in french but in mostly in english (some things are still in french, like some notifications on the lockscreen). 
and the main bug is that the "application" scopes reboot non stop. It doesn't display anything, just the white background, then close, and reboot.
I can launch the apps that are on the unity launcher (the left bar) : calls, sms, terminal app, web browser.. but once I'm in those apps, it switch back to the scopes when it reboot.

EDIT : 
I let the phone running, and drain the battery, Once charged the phone, it didn't fixed anything of course. 
Using the ubuntu sdk and trying to ssh into it doesn't work since the peripheral cannot be opened as the massage says. 
I'm trying to open it from my computer, but I don't expect much from it.

EDIT2 : I tried everything to mount the device, to fix the MTP bullshit, etc. 
Nothing worked, I had all my contact list stored somewhere, I back up my photographies and video often, etc. 
The only sad thing is that I was playing pokemon and will probably lost my saves by reseting the phone. That's overkill, but I only see this solution.

EDIT3 : It didn't fix anything. What should I do now ? contact bq ?

EDIT4 : I found that the OTA-4 was coming so I just waited. The update fixed everything. 
My conclusion is that if it happens to you, if there is an update coming soon just wait some days, else you can contact BQ directly because there were no solution possible.